# Saving the wrong sheet in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

***Some Background***

My excel workbook "Workbook_Original" has 2 sheets - sheet1 and sheet2

I want to save sheet2 as a text file using the name "Workbook_New" (note that this name is located in cell A3 of sheet1)

***Please see my code below***

```
Sub export_as_text_1()
      Dim saveName As String
      saveName = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3")
      ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2).SaveAs Filename:=saveName, FileFormat:=21
      'FileFormat 21 is text file
End Sub
```

***problems I am facing***

Problem 1 - when I run the program it saves sheet1 as text file instead.  I want to save sheet2 as a text file

Problem 2 - my excel window for "Workbook_Original" is closed and replaced with an excel window for "Workbook_New".  How can I prevent this? I want to keep "Workbook_Original" open in excel.  I do not want "Workbook_New" to open.

I appreciate all of your feedback and suggestions.

I want to export sheet2 as a text file (as described above).  I also don’t want my workbook to keep closing.  I want to force it to remain open (as described above).  I am not sure how to debug this…

Comment: `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Copy`, which creates a new workbook with just that sheet, then save the new workbook.

Comment: You're aslso missing a double Quote after `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2)` should be `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")`

Comment: Is this code located in `Workbook_Original`?